# TempData status message from partial view of another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

Having an issue trying to get `TempData` messages back from a partial view,
I am rendering a partial view of another controller in my main view like so:

```
@{
    UserProfile Model = ViewData["model"] as UserProfile;
}

@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/MyProfile/Index.cshtml", Model);
}
```

However I cant seem to access the TempData messages of this partial view in my Main view or even in the PartialView? Nothing is displayed after I submit the changes.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Update(UserProfile model, HttpPostedFileBase Picture)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Picture != null && Picture.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // delete first
                string todelete = model.PreviousPicture;
                if (todelete != null && !todelete.Equals(""))
                {
                    //....
                }

                //....

                UserProfile up = _db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == model.UserId);
                //....

                try
                {
                    UpdateModel(up);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "Please ensure all required fields are supplied.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //...
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    TempData["Success"] = "Profile was updated successfully.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            }
            else
            {

                UserProfile up = _db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == model.UserId);

                //.....
                try
                {
                    UpdateModel(up);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "Please ensure all required fields are supplied.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _db.Entry(up).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    TempData["Success"] = "Profile was updated successfully.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
        }

        TempData["Message"] = "Please ensure all required fields are supplied.";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

In the partial view I display the messages like so:

```
@Html.Partial("_ValidationPartial")
```

However once redirected after I submit, no message is displayed in the partial?

This is the _validationPartial:

```
@if (!Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
    {
        foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-error alert-warning alert-dismissable message-error"
                 style="font-size: 13px; color: #d01616; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 10px;
       text-align:left;padding-left:30px;">
                @error.ErrorMessage
            </div>
        }
    }
    <br />
}

@if (@TempData["Message"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-error alert-warning alert-dismissable message-error"
         style="font-size: 13px; color: #d01616; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 10px;
       text-align:left;padding-left:30px;">
        @TempData["Message"]
    </div>
    <br />
}
@if (@TempData["Success"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success message-success"
         style="font-size: 13px; color: green; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 10px;
       text-align:left;padding-left:30px;">
        @TempData["Success"]
    </div>
    <br />
}
```

Comment: Where is `ViewBag.StatusMessage` defined in the Controller or in the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RedirectToAction()` returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action. It makes the ViewState
errors disappear.

Returning `View(model)` instead of `RedirectToAction()` may help.

Comment: Modified the response, hope this helps.